# AngularJS ng-repeat directives is not working on my EventController.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to add session details under address and date. But ng-repeat is working but it`s not displaying any details under sessions section. It`s not giving me any error. Can anyone please check my codes and let me know what`s missing.

.....app.js.....

'use strict';

var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', []);

```js
'use strict';


eventsApp.controller('EventController',
                    
    function EventController($scope){
   $scope.event = {
       name: 'Angular Event App',
       date: '04/02/2017',
       time: '3.09 am',
       location: {
           address: 'Google Headquaters',
           city: 'Mountain View',
           Province: 'CA'
       },
       imageUrl: '/img/angularjs-logo.png',
       sessions: [
           {
               name: 'Directive Masterclass'
           },
           {
               name: 'Scope for fun and profit'
           },
           {
               name: 'well Behaved Controllers'
           }
       ]
   }; 
});
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="eventsApp">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Event Registration</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
        <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/underscore-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav">
    
    
                </ul>
    
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="EventController" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px">
                <img ng-src="{{event.imageUrl}}" alt="{{event.name}}" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span1">
                        <h2> {{event.name}}</h2>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span2">
                        <div><strong>Date: </strong> {{event.date}}</div>
                        <div><strong>Time: </strong> {{event.time}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <address>
                    <strong> Address: </strong><br>
                        {{event.location.address}}<br>
                        {{event.location.city}}, {{event.location.province}}
                    </address>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
               
                
                <h3>Sessions</h3>
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li ng-repeat="session in event.sessions" ></li>
                    <div class="row session">
                    <div class="well span9">
                        <h4 class="well-title">{{session.name}}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                </ul>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

[image: There is nothing is showin up under sessions section.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the div content inside the `li` tag

change this

```
<li ng-repeat="session in event.sessions" ></li>
        <div class="row session">
         <div class="well span9">
            <h4 class="well-title">{{session.name}}</h4>
        </div>
 </div>
```

to this

```
<li ng-repeat="session in event.sessions">
      <div class="row session">
            <div class="well span9">
         <h4 class="well-title">{{session.name}}</h4>              
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/VkoL4DtRDJbkIn24E2AR?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Md Mehadi Hasan Mozumder no prob :D

Answer (score 1):

The ending tag for the li element is before where you are referencing the item from the Ng-repeat (likely a typo). I'd update the HTML to the following:

```
<li ng-repeat="session in event.sessions">
    <div class="row session">
        <div class="well span9">
            <h4 class="well-title">{{session.name}}</h4>
       </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.